# How to dump pickle file into new lines?

Tags: python, pickle

Here's my code:

```
f = open("cities.txt", 'wb')
pickle.dump(city_list, f)
f.close()
```

I know normally to print a list vertically, into new lines, you do this inside a print statement: print(*city_list, sep='\n'). I want to know if there's a way to do this when creating the pickle file, so that when you open it, you see a vertical list, without having to do anything else. For example, when I open the file:

```
fh = open("cities.txt", 'rb')
x = pickle.load(fh)
print(x)
```

I want the output to be a vertical list without me having to add a sep='\n' to the print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have loaded your pickled data, it has been converted to a regular Python list already. What you are asking is then: How can I print the items of a list, one item per line?

The answer is simply to do this:

```
for item in x:
    print(item)
```

If instead you want the output file to be more easily readable by a human, you should encode your data in a format other than what Python's pickling module offers.

Using CSV:

```
import csv

city_list = [
    ('Montreal', 'Canada'),
    ('Belmopan', 'Belize'),
    ('Monaco', 'Monaco'),
]

with open('cities.txt', 'w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    for city, country in city_list:
        writer.writerow(city, country)
```

This will result in cities.txt containing the following:

> Montreal,Canada
>
> Belmopan,Belize
>
> Monaco,Monaco

Comment: Note that there are many more ways that you can achieve this. Some are more suited to large volumes of data. This is the simplest, most "pythonic" way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but I was more so looking for a way to show a vertical list when I open the file without me having to do anything else. Like maybe I need to do something when dumping the file to make it print vertically when you open it.

Comment: The pickle format is unfortunately not human-readable. If you squint hard, you can make out words and strings from your original data, but if you want your data to be readable, you will have to use a generic format that allows some formatting, like JSON, YAML or XML, or you will have to devise your own format. Have you considered using CSV?

Comment: I think I'll try using JSON then. Thank you!

Comment: JSON as is will probably not output new lines between array elements. You will need a JSON writer that is sophisticated enough to do "pretty printing".